# Hyperlink button doesn't respond: iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, url, hyperlink

Basically I've thoroughly looked everywhere I could for a solution and it seems I do everything right when assigning the URL link to a button. The problem is it does not respond at all. Just does nothing.

The code:

```
- (IBAction)firstViewBackButton:(id)sender {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)red:(id)sender {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]];
}
```

The button **red** is in .h and .m files. **red** is linked with code.

I read a fix where it seemed that I should go to File>Restore...smthing and it somehow enables Safari in the simulator. But I do not have such option in the simulator File section.

I would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This
Replace

```
[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]];
```

with

```
[NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://www.google.com"  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
-canOpenURL:
```

it is a function which gives BOOL result.

the answer is

```
- (IBAction)red:(id)sender {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]){
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
    }
}
```

if the application can open that url it opens